# How can I disable full screen mode on Mac OS in my PyQT app?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a simple PyQt app and I'm trying to either prevent the app from going into full screen mode when the green maximize button is clicked (ideal behavior) OR disabling the action entirely (if the first cannot be done). I've tried removing one of the window flags but it appears to have no effect:

```
class AppWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, main_widget):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowFullscreenButtonHint)
```

I think this is actually supposed to remove the maximize button, but it does't even do that. I'd prefer if the maximum button is kept, but prevented from going into fullscreen mode or if I could override the button behavior somehow

Comment: My only mac computer is very old, so I don't know about changes in the new versions, but AFAIK, the green button should *maximize* the window, which is not the same as "full screen": full screen makes the window occupying *all* screen, without showing the mac menu bar and window title bar, while maximizing means that the window is resized to occupy all *available* space of the screen, but still showing the title bar and the mac menu bar. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @musicamante Yeah, I believe this behavior changed for Mac a few years ago. For most apps, PyQT or otherwise, if you click the green button it full screens the app and hides the menu and title bar unless you push your mouse up to the top to bring them down. I'm trying to maximize while still showing the menu bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't terribly well documented anywhere, but I found it in some random posts and it appears to work:

```
self.setWindowFlags((self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowFullscreenButtonHint) | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
```

This adds the CustomizeWindowHint which allows you to remove WindowFullscreenButtonHint flag and actually have it applied.